# How do I protect against onmouseover from a WYSIWYG using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss

I current have a WYSIWYG editor for basic formatting. I need to add some security measures to prevent XSS and any other JS from being added to the code but allow things like bold, underline, and anchor tags..

I have added DOmPurify but it's not stripping out onmouseover events.

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: AcronymUtils.decodeHtmlEntities(DOMPurify.sanitize('<p>&lt;p onmouseover="(function() {alert(\'test\')})()"&gt;Testing on mouse over&lt;/p&gt;</p>')) }} />
```

Im looking for what are best practices for handling this, are there are any libraries I can use that will help or if I need to do some fancy regex to remove this sort of behavior?